# Join and nest two associative arrays / geoJSON files

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two geoJSON files that I would like to nest for a D3 visualization. This question would equally apply to two associative arrays / objects in javascript. Is this the most concise way of doing it? How could I generate the key name ["communities"] from variable name used for the second array? This uses the underscore / lodash function _.where(). Since I am using d3 is there a way to do this without the lo-dash dependency (not essential, but if there is a built-in d3 function to do this, better).

```
var nationalities = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "nationality": "Cofan"
    },
    "geometry": null
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "nationality": "Secoya"
    },
    "geometry": null
  }
];

var communities = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "community": "Dureno",
      "nationality": "Cofan"
    },
    "geometry": null
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "community": "Zabalo",
      "nationality": "Cofan"
    },
    "geometry": null
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "community": "Duvono",
      "nationality": "Cofan"
    },
    "geometry": null
  }
];


var nested = nest(nationalities, communities, "nationality");

console.log(nested);

function nest(array1, array2, id) {
  var filterFunc = function(feature) { 
    return function(d) {
      return feature.properties[id] === d.properties[id];
    };
  };

  array1.forEach(function(feature) {
    feature.properties["communities"] = _.filter(array2, filterFunc(feature));
  })

  return array1;
}
```

Comment: It's better that you show here the code you tried to use and tell what's your problem with it. Check the guides [ask] and [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: wouldn't topojson be able to do what you need? 
https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference

Comment: Thanks b, I have tried to improve the question with code.

Comment: tomtomtom, topoJSON is similar to what I need, in particular the join code which is similar but not exactly what I want http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5323061 (joins a csv/tsv to a geojson, but not a geojson to geojson).